# static_cast and explicit conversion operators

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

I have found that the following code gives a compile error on gcc 4.7.3 but not on clang 3.3:

```
#include <cstdint>                                          

struct X {
    explicit operator uint32_t() { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    static_cast< int >( X() );
    return 0;
}
```

The question is, which is right? Gcc 4.7.3 says:

```
testcast.cpp:8:29: error: invalid static_cast from type 'X' to type 'int'
```

What I think happens is that clang uses the uint32_t operator to get an unsigned and then implicitly converts that to int. I suspect the spec does not leave this undefined, and as such I'd expect one of the compilers to be wrong.

Comment: AFAIK, you'd still need to explicitly cast to `uint32_t`.

Comment: In this case, I think GCC is right in rejecting this code. Chained-conversion is not allowed: means, if `A` can convert into `B` which can convert into `C`, it does NOT mean `A` can *directly* convert into `C`.

Comment: @chris, yes that will work on both, but that's not quite what I'm asking -- this happens inside a relatively deep stack of templates, and clang will call a different function from gcc because it has a different idea of what is a valid expression. I like the gcc behaviour more in this case I guess, as I don't want the unsigned->signed conversion to happen "behind my back" (the conversions are explicit for a reason). But I'd rather know for sure which is right. :-)

Comment: @mornfall, I'm implying that GCC is correct, but I'm not completely sure. If Clang 3.4 rejects it, too, that's almost certainly the correct behaviour.

Comment: Tip-of-trunk clang rejects this with a very similar error message.

Answer (score 3):

You must explicitly cast it to `uint32_t`, otherwise a compile error. You should try this:

```
static_cast< uint32_t >( X() );
```

So, If it doesn't make error in clang-3.3, it seems as a bug.

*Observation: [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c9666ed2eb528f0) and [Clang-3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd160695290e6207) both reject the code and make compile errors.*

Comment: The links you provided show a failure in both, but completely unrelated to my question (gcc is running in C++98 mode failing to even recognize the "explicit" keyword; clang says `main.cpp:8:23: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'`)

Comment: See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9ce1d9926cba0f1) -- I don't know what version of clang that web runs, but it compiles the code without complaint if you actually tell it that it is C++11. (edit: it says `clang version 3.4 (trunk 184460)`; hence even clang 3.4 claims the code is OK)